# In category.php I need to get the next 10/previous 10 posts

Tags: categories, navigation

I have a site that uses categories to output posts into categories.php. I don't have single posts using single.php

What I need is for a 'next 10' / 'previous 10' links in the category a site visitor is looking at. Here's my code from category.php

```
<?php if (is_category('black-metal')) : ?>
<h2><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/black-metal-h2.png" alt="Black Metal" /></h2>
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=2&posts_per_page=10' ); ?>
<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php elseif (is_category('death-metal')) : ?>
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=10' ); ?>
<h2><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/death-metal-h2.png" alt="Death Metal" /></h2>
<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?> 
<?php the_content(); ?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

So for example if someone is looking at the Black Metal category, I want next 10/previous 10 links for that particular category.

Hope that makes sense. I've done a lot searching but haven't been able to find an answer to this.

Comment: is '10 posts per page' the same number as you have set under 'Settings' - 'Reading'? generally, start by reading https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/

Comment: Yes it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

if the only difference in the category archives is the images, you can work without a custom query.
in this case you could use (as suggested here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/#simple-pagination ):

```
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>     
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
```

or any other suggestion from https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/

for the image, you need to change the `img` line in your category.php:

```
<h2><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); if( is_category( 'black-metal') ) { echo '/assets/img/black-metal-h2.png" alt="Black Metal"'; } elseif( is_category( 'death-metal') ) { echo '/assets/img/death-metal-h2.png" alt="Death Metal"'; } ?>/></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer was quite simple in the end. Thanks for all the input. The answer I needed wa here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_posts_pagination/